# How to include 4 more JVM instances?

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to include 4 more JVMs to check logs are exiting or not and also want include those 4 More jvms to pull logs to path, as per below script. How can I modify the script which can used for multiple JVM?

```
#!/bin/bash
Minute=$(expr `date +%M` - 15)
Hour=$(expr `date +%H`)
Current_Time=$(date +%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S)
f=$(find /apps_01/webapps/JBoss/logs/xxxx JVM1_server*/http_logs/ -name  access_log.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log |wc -l)
if [ "$f" -gt 0 ]
then
tail -500 /apps_01/webapps/JBoss/logs/xxxx JVM1_server*/http_logs/access_log.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log|awk '{print $4}'| cut -d '[' -f2 >> /home/tmp/xxx_logs
h=$(awk -F'[: ]' '{print $2}' /home/tmp/xxx_logs|tail -1)
if [ "$h" -ge "$Hour" ]
then
for m in `awk -F'[: ]' '{print $3}' /home/tmp/xxx_logs`
do
if [ "$m" -ge "$Minute" ]
then
echo $m
fi
done
fi
fi
```

Comment: Are you talking about `JVM1_server*/`? With same log file `access_log.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log `?

Comment: It looks like you want help with modifying a shell script. When you tried those modifications yourself, what problem did you run into? Unfortunately, if you want someone to write it for you, that is rather too broad for Stack Overflow, especially since we do not want to become known as a place where free work can be requested. Are you able to narrow down the question at all?

Comment: You can indent and comment code to make it readable and maintainable...

Comment: Why do you use `expr`?